Can a sinner volunteer for punishment?
If a person knows that he commited an aveira (sin), and knows what the punishment is and wants the kapara (atonement), but the court does not administer the punishment due to lack of evidence, witness warning or some other technicality, can he volunteer for the punishment, e.g.:

A person breaks Shabbat on purpose. Can he voluneer for the death penalty?
A person ate blood. Can he volunteer for lashes?

Can he excommunicate himself? Can he volunteer as an Eved Yisrael?
I suppose the answer is no, a person cannot be witness to his own crimes (Yevamot 25b). Are there any special provisions to the courts, or is there any form of simply volunteering for the punishments, and if not, what is a person to do in such a situation where they genuinely do want the atonement?

Tanya, Igeres HaTeshuva recommends limited fasting and giving tzedaka generously. But from what I understand, the Rebbe was opposed to taking on personal fasts at all and instead encouraged people to focus on positive improvements.

@shmosel he recommends these for what specifically? Tanya was composed after the abilities for the Beit Din to administer lashes or mita were removed, btw, so maybe he is talking about times like these only

The remedy for someone who sinned but isn't punishable by beis din is bringing a korban. Tanya is offering a substitute for us who don't have that option.

@shmosel I am more interested in your first statement and that's the kind of answer I am looking for. So, someone who broke Shabbat on purpose, but there were no witness, should bring a voluntary korban? If yes, to what extent does that produce the same kappara as the punishment by beit din had there been witnesses?

Breaking Shabbos without witnesses is punishable by kares. That doesn't require beis din to administer.

I'm actually not sure when exactly a korban is applicable. Rambam Hilchos Teshuva discusses different types of atonement but says the essential thing is repentance.

@shmosel yes I think your line of thinking is extremely complicated - not that it isn't necessarily the line to the answer. If a person wants to avoid kares, is there a way to volunteer for skila? (btw, this question is not lma'aseh bH) or is the answer "no, in that case, teshuva is as good as skila"

It seems that Rabbeinu Yonah's "Shaarei Teshuvah" is quite explicit about it with its 20+ steps of attonement. I prefer  Hebrew edition with a good thorough peirush or translation of R. Yaakov Feldman.

If a person wants to avoid kares, is there a way to volunteer for skila? I'm pretty sure beis din wouldn't accept volunteers for punishment. And even inflicting it on oneself is probably forbidden, but see here for some interesting discussion.

At least in the death penalty cases, isn’t it a thing that the king would usually execute the guys who got off on a technicality? So that’s that solution

A Talmid Chacham can excommunicate himself (Nedarim 7b)

@shmosel one of the distinguishing points the Tanya makes about fasting is that the fasting itself is not teshuva but rather comes after teshuva has been done already. It is compared to a gift to a friend after the apology in order to rekindle the friendship and a karbon olah. One of the main reasons to then be against fasting despite its tremendous potential is if it will awaken that person's resolve in serving Hashem and this be counter productive. Fasting should then be reserved for those special individuals that can handle it best.

@RabbiKaii the court is not supposed to judge on these cases, and a person has to bring korban after making teshuvah. Rabbeinu Yonah has a full program in Shaarei Teshuvah.

I'd combine the Gemmora in Sanhedrin 37b (also Sotah and Ktubos):

"וכן תני דבי חזקיה: מיום שחרב בית המקדש אף על פי שבטלה סנהדרי,
ארבע מיתות לא בטלו.
לא בטלו? והא בטלו?
אלא דין ארבע מיתות לא בטלו:
מי שנתחייב סקילה או נופל מן הגג או חיה דורסתו מי שנתחייב שריפה או נופל בדליקה או נחש מכישו" וכו'


"..."The halakha of the four types of court-imposed capital punishment has not ceased to be applicable.

with the principle "עביד איניש דינא לנפשיה" ("a person adjudicates for himself" Bava Kamma.27b) in the lack of an authoritative Beis Din (I'm aware that the discussion covers exclusively civil law, though),
and infer that, although many would find it ethically troublesome, the answer is positive - a person can execute or lash himself.
IIRC, a Talmudic character did perform all four Capital deaths on himself to atone for his sins, and the rabbis didn't object (source needed).

I can't quite comprehend all your statements, could you reword for clarity when you get a chance, I think I like it

1 the laws of the four capital punishments apply today even without BD. 2 a person is allowed to adjudicate for himself and execute the verdict 3 ergo, one can afflict capital or corporal punishment on himself

In criminal law, a person is innocent until proven guilty. In Jewish law, a person is guilty, at least by Heavenly standards, once sinned, regardless of human witness or judgment. Agreed?
The rest is an atonement principle - a person must atone for misdeeds. He can try different paths - prayers, Tzeddaka, fasting, community work, etc.
Since we know that capital or corporal punishments work as 100% atonement for specific sins, we can use it as a shortcut. Sounds plausible.

@AlBerko you are correct, but prior to kaparah a person must do Teshuvah. Otherwise it is not going to work. Rabbeinu Yonah in Shaarei Teshuvah explains all of that.

@YDJ Apparently, one who's about to execute himself had already passed the Teshuva stage.

@AlBerko not really. Death is kaparah. Why does it say, repent 1 day before you die(Pirkei Avos 2:10)

@YDJ The mere desire to kill yourself in atonement points to the Teshuva, doesn't it?

@AlBerko Atonement and teshuvah are different things. Rabbeinu Yonah in "Shaarei Teshuvah" describes the process of teshuvah in chapters 1-3. The last chapter 4 explains atonement. There is no atonement WITHOUT teshuvah.

On a more practical level - the question would be the equivalent of:
Since a perp isn't made to pay for damages if he also deserves lashes or the death penalty for the same action, does that absolve him from payment?
Rabbi David Lapin in his Matmonim shiur on Bava Metzia 91a titled Moral Conscience discusses this and states that it's clear that בדיני שמים he is obligated to pay.
So, after being killed by Beth Din, when he gets to the heavenly court, the perp will receive a punishment for not paying his victim for the monetary damages he caused.
Back to your examples, if the Bet Din doesn't administer the punishment he deserves, he would do himself a favor if he asked Rabbinic advice on how to atone for his sin.
